# null values showing in flask_restplus posting method the code is below

Tags: python, flask-restplus

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,json,request,Response
from flask_restplus import Api,reqparse,Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

company_detaile = [{'name': 'nithin', 'age': 45, 'company': 'pix', 'sex': 'male'}]

@api.route('/hello')

class Member(Resource):
    def __init__ (self,args):
        self.parser= reqparse.RequestParser()
    def get(self):
        return jsonify({'details':company_detaile})


    def post(self):
        self.parser.add_argument("name", action='append', location='json', type=str)
        self.parser.add_argument("age", action='append', location='json', type=int)
        self.parser.add_argument("company", action='append', location='json', type=str)
        self.parser.add_argument("sex", action='append', location='json', type=str)
        args=self.parser.parse_args()
        company_detaile.append(args)
        print(args)
        print(company_detaile)
        return jsonify({"append_detaile":'ok'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

when i try to post this will show. i am using tool is postman

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "age": 45, 
      "company": "pix", 
      "name": "nithin", 
      "sex": "male"
    }, 
    {
      "age": null, 
      "company": null, 
      "name": null, 
      "sex": null
    }
  ]
}
```

how i can solve this error? Feel free to ask details about the code lines that I've omitted,in the comment section. please help me to solve this error

Comment: are you sure there is a posted payload? look in `flask.Request.values` or `flask.Request.json` while inside you `post` function

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to have the parser adding arguments in the post method. Moving this out of the method and adding the decorator `@api.expect(parser)` will allow you to parse arguments correctly.

Also worth noting that you should now use [flask-restx](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) rather than flask_restplus as restplus is no longer maintained.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restx import Api, reqparse, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

company_detaile = [{"name": "nithin", "age": 45, "company": "pix", "sex": "male"}]

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument("name", location="json", type=str)
parser.add_argument("age", location="json", type=int)
parser.add_argument("company", location="json", type=str)
parser.add_argument("sex", location="json", type=str)


@api.route("/hello", methods=["POST", "GET"])
class Member(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return jsonify({"details": company_detaile})

    @api.expect(parser)
    def post(self):
        company_detaile.append(request.json)
        return jsonify({"details": company_detaile})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Testing with

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:5000/hello" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"name\": \"John Smith\", \"age\": 42, \"company\": \"Aperture Science\", \"sex\": \"Male\"}"
```

returns

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "age": 45,
      "company": "pix",
      "name": "nithin",
      "sex": "male"
    },
    {
      "age": 42,
      "company": "Aperture Science",
      "name": "John Smith",
      "sex": "Male"
    }
  ]
}
```